# how to add an widget into the Form In QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt4

in qdesigner_workbench.cpp, how can I add a widget (say QLabel) into a FormWindow by code? 
Since methods like createWidget()...etc are all abstract, how do I properly use the internal mechanics to add QLabel into the active FormWindow?

EDIT:

In qdesigner_workbench.cpp, this is currently what I have:

```
QDesignerFormWindowManagerInterface* fwm = core()->formWindowManager();
QDesignerFormWindowInterface* fw = fwm->activeFormWindow();

QWidget* mw = fw->mainContainer(); 

QLabel* label = new QLabel(mw);         //can be added correctly but not in the right hierarchy
label->setText("I am a good girl.");
```

The mw (obtained from fw->mainContainer()) is actually a MainWindow, however the real data I need is in:

```
mw -> children[2] (which is a QDesignerWidget) -> children
```

There are 9 widgets in the designer, and you can see there's 9 arrays in children mentioned above; see this link (an image) for illustration.

http://img24.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=98871_a_122_476lo.jpg

So... how can I correctly add the QLabel widget? 
Tried both

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(fw);   // will be a sibling of MainContainer, which is the QMainWindow (mw) in this case
QLabel* label = new QLabel(mw);   // will be a sibling of QDesignerWidget
```

and apprarently either of the works.

Answer (score 5):

If you want just to display a widget on a form, you can set your QMainWindow or QDialog to be the widget parent:

```
QLabel *l = new QLabel(this);
l->setText("My long string");
```

Where **this** is a pointer pointing to your current QDialog or QMainWindow.

Otherwise as ufukgun pointed out, you can use setCentralWidget if you need your widget to occupy the center of the QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

You should [add](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qlayout.html#add) any QWidget to the QLayout of the form.This will put it into the display strategy of the form when resizing it.

```
form->ui->layout->add(yourQWidget);
```

Depending of the [`QLayout`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qlayout.html) you are using, parameters of the add function will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

create a widget and add it to your main window as it is your central widget

`mainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);`

if you want to add a label, you can add it to this central widget